# MongoDb - No joins: duplicate or ugly query?

Tags: mongodb

Here's the situation. Let's say I have a standardized item like a product, with a sku.  Let's say that every day I check the price of each sku in the system and record the history.  Let's also say that users can track individual skus that they're interested in.

Currently I'm storing data like this:

Users
Skus
PriceHistory

Skus has a list of all the interested users, as well as a summary object with most recent price, etc.  So when the price is updated we resummarize and update the sku.  For normal views you just pull the skus that have the user in the list.

There is also a graph that shows the history of a sku, which is easy to pull.

The problem is when I'm going to show a graph with all of a users skus.  Now I don't seem to have a good option (this is where SQL suddenly seems awesome).

I can either a) store the list of users with each PriceHistory, or I can run one query to pull the list of skus for a user and then run a 'or' type query across price history.

Or maybe there's a better option?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're doing embedded documents of users inside the product object. If you frequently need to access the user directly, then you might not be using the best design. You can still do relation between documents just like in relational database. You don't have to use embedded documents.

I don't know your system so well to judge, but you might want to consider separating the two documents and making relation between them.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear.  Each of the 3 document types I listed are being stored separately (not embedded).  The Sku has a list of just User Ids embedded in it.

Comment: ohh ok, sorry.

can you do query like this on on SKU:

query: { sku.users._id: <_ID> }

I have similar query, but it's for embedded documents. Is yours that, or just an Array of values?